# CRM 2011 - Qualify lead

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, xrm

Does anyone know how lead qualifying works internally?

Please, consider following scenario:
I created new lead record, so I am an owner and it was created by me of course.
I have a worflow registered on onCreate of lead, this workflow is owned by another user and it sets one field on newly created record. 
So my new lead record has these lookups:  Owner - me, CreatedBy - me, ModifiedBy - another user. 
If I want now to Qualify a lead, I check the Account and Opprtunity checkboxes in Qualify lead dialog and hit OK, then I have got missing privillege record (create Opportunity). 
My user has User privillege on Create of Opportunity.
CRM wants to use ModifiedBy user as owner and creator for new Opportunity record, it is the only explanation.

So my another question is whether someone knows whether this is an OOB behavior of CRM or there is plugin or something in my organization I am working on. (I did not find such a plugin or workflow or script).

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: AccessCheckExFailed errors should provide you the GUID of the user, for you to verify who's acting.

Answer (score 0):

the owner of the lead should become the owner of the opportunity. Try giving bu permissions over opportunity.